# External Hard Drive won't mount. How can I transfer the files?

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount

[image]

I have a Buffalo mini station that I believe has died. It will not mount and will not repair in disk utility. It will not mount in terminal. How can I transfer the files from the dead external hard drive to another external hard drive? Please help before I throw it trough the window. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities.

1. The disk itself has failed. You now need a high-powered recovery program like Data Rescue, or a service like DriveSavers. Cost is about $100 for the first and $1000 for the second.
2. The case has a problem. Given that it's a Buffalo case I think this is more likely (their products are rather low quality). Get a new case or a drive dock, open the old case, remove the drive and put it in the new case / dock.